# How to Replace backslash(\) in data in Impala

Tags: impala

select translate('Parts and Supplies \ Compressors','\','0');
**Output **:  Parts and Supplies  Compressors

I tried replacing the \ with 0 but translate or regex_replace or replace are not working.

Please let me know a workaround for this

Answer (score 0):

add one more `\` to escape the replace character.

```
replace(mycol,'\\','|')
```

if you want to split this string, you can use split part function.

```
select split_part( replace(mycol,'\\','|'),'|',1) split_first part
```

[image: ss]

Comment: 'Parts and Supplies \ Compressors' is a column data in a table. It has \(backslash) as a delimiter in it. My requirement is to split the data into two using the \ as delimiter.  Even replace is not working as expected.

Comment: this is the Output
select replace('Parts and Supplies \ Compressors','\\','0');
Parts and Supplies  Compressors

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/6430523/koushik-roy Your inputs on this please?

Comment: i have updated my answer, could you pls check?

Comment: Nope its not working. See below output with query.

Query :  select split_part(replace('Parts and Supplies \ Compressors','\\','|'),'|',1);
Output:  Parts and Supplies  Compressors

Comment: One more change to the actual input data.

Data : Parts and Supplies\Compressors

There is no space between the backslash. The above is how the actual data from source system is. I am not able to replace that single backslash nor split the data with backslash as delimiter.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/6430523/koushik-roy

Comment: Ues original col and dont use hardcode value.... Use like i did in my code. Spcce shouldn't matter

Comment: Thank you so much @https://stackoverflow.com/users/6430523/koushik-roy . It is working fine. But just want to understand why hardcoded value of the same data did not work and using the column worked?

Comment: Because the single \works as escape character in a string. So in input string it acts  like an escape character and treat the space after that like a special char. In other words, if you want to see correct result try with \\.

Comment: Use this to check `select replace('my \\ col', '\\','|')`. It should return 'my | col'.